# VSCode: What's that green statusbar terminal-ish icon in October 2019 release notes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons, statusbar

In vscode's [October 2019 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_themable-window-border) there're some pictures of the vscode window, containing a green statusbar icon on the bottom left with `><` text inside it.

Does anyone know what it's for & where can I get it? It [looks](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_40/window-border.gif) [really](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_40/outline_filtered.png) [awesome](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_40/minimap-scaling.gif) [for](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_40/definition-preview-hover.gif) [sure](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_40/icon-symbols.png). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the "[Remote Development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack)" extension by Microsoft.